# Is it possible to enable X11 forwarding on windows to windows?

Tags: windows-10, x11, openssh

I managed to connect to a win10 through putty, using newest openssh.

I am not sure it is so-called Microsoft support the ssh. And whether the openssh is almost fully functional.

While, at least i can connect to it through putty(kitty actually). I tried to set X11. Of course I know how to config x11, like localhost:0 and enable X11Forwarding.

Then I tried to execute sublime_text.exe through ssh. The process is up but no UI, is it possible to make X11 up? Or something like X11 that support win-system?

Comment: Did you ever happen to get this working from windows to windows? I'm having the same issue where the UI does not pop up, but only on windows to windows. I'm a bit confused by the accepted answer because it is referring to Unix locations.

Comment: As far as i know this does ot work, as Windows does not use the X Window System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get X11 forwarding working over ssh, you'll need 3 things in place.
1.Your client must be set up to forward X11.
2.Your server must be set up to allow X11 forwarding.
3.Your server must be able to set up X11 authentication.

If you have both #1 and #2 in place but are missing #3, then you'll end up with an empty DISPLAY environment variable.

X11 forwarding needs to be enabled on both the client side and the server side.

On the client side, the -X (capital X) option to ssh enables X11 forwarding, and you can make this the default (for all connections or for a specific conection) with ForwardX11 yes in ~/.ssh/config.

On the server side, X11Forwarding yes must specified in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Note that the default is no forwarding (some distributions turn it on in their default /etc/ssh/sshd_config), and that the user cannot override this setting.

The xauth program must be installed on the server side. If there are any X11 programs there, it's very likely that xauth will be there. In the unlikely case xauth was installed in a nonstandard location, it can be called through ~/.ssh/rc (on the server!).

Note that you do not need to set any environment variables on the server. DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY will automatically be set to their proper values. If you run ssh and DISPLAY is not set, it means ssh is not forwarding the X11 connection.

To confirm that ssh is forwarding X11, check for a line containing Requesting X11 forwarding in the ssh -v -X output. Note that the server won't reply either way.

Also please see http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html

Comment: This whole answer seems like it is meant for \*nix/Linux-to-\*nix/Linux setup (mentions of distributions, *nix paths), not for a Windows-SSH'ing-to-another-Windows, neither of which may have an X server running at all. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

You should setup the Xming X-window client before connecting via Putty with enabled X11Forwarding.

Here is a very nice step-by-step guide for your problem:

http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)